# Can anyone help me understand the difference in shading on these 2 models?

Tags: shaders

Can anyone help me understand the difference in shading on these 2 models and how I can get the rough one smooth like the smooth one? It's not just shading flat or smooth.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1v-b0n7Qkr_4s5f15MP2WX5M1nn1l0x-V?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left bush (the smooth one) has *Custom Split Normal Data*. You can delete it in *Object Data Properties > Geometry Data*. There is a button to remove it. Then the bush looks like the bush on the right side.

If you want to have the right bush look like the left one then add a *Normal Edit* modifier. Use type `Radial` (default) with *Mix Mode* set to `Copy` (default) and a *Mix > Mix Factor* of `0.950`. In *Object Data Properties > Normals* the *Auto Smooth* checkbox must be enabled.

Comment: That was it, thank you!

Comment: 3 mins too late for me :(